# Multiple Instance of a class updating all values when using =

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have custom class like the below;

```
Public MyClass
  Public Property MyText() As String
End Class
```

Then in my code page I have the following VB.NET code;

```
Dim obj1 As New MyClass
Dim obj2 As New MyClass

obj1 = obj2
obj1.MyText = "Test"
```

My problem is that when the below piece of code is executed the obj2.MyText is updated as well. How can I avoid this?

```
obj1.MyText = "Test"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
obj1 = obj2
```

That copies the value of `obj2` to `obj1`. That value is *not* the object - it's a *reference* to the object. So now `obj1` and `obj2` refer to the same object, so any changes you make via one variable *will* be seen by the other.

I realize this is VB rather than C#, but you may still find my [article on reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) useful. Fundamentally, you need to grok how reference types behave.

Comment: Is there a work around? instead of having to set all properties manually?

Comment: @AlanAgius: Well you could potentially get a shallow clone using `Object.MemberwiseClone`, but you'd need to work out whether there were some properties which needed deeper cloning etc.

Comment: @AlanAgius: If your object is serializable, You could serialize the object and then deserialize it to a new object.  For the most part, this is functionally equivalent to creating a deep clone.  However, this technique is less efficient than a hand-coded deep clone.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that obj1 is not a copy of obj2 but is a reference. When changing obj1, obj2 is automatically changed as well, since it points to the same memory location/instance.

Answer (score -1):

This happened, because .NET is based on pointers.

So you assign a **poiter**. Not **Value**.

You have to use function to copy data from **obj2**  to **obj1**

For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy.aspx#Y100

Comment: This is only true of reference types (classes), not value types (structures).

Comment: Please talk about references, not pointers.  References are generally implemented using pointers (which are generally implemented as addresses), but this is an implementation detail.  See Eric Lippert's article, [References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx).